# Changing piece of top bar color in Foundation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Alright, so I'm mildly new to using Foundation and I've tried several 'fixes' I've found about all sorts of support, but I still can't figure it out. The bit circled in red won't change to the same pink as the rest?

Alright, I had an image, but I don't have the reputation to post it. Basically, I got the code to work for all my drop downs, but not for the small rectangle off to the left that has nothing in it.

I found a snatch of code off another person's question here on StackOverflow and modified it...

```
.top-bar {
    background: #FF859C !important;
}

.top-bar-section li a:not(.button) {
    background: #FF859C !important;   
}

.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover {
    background: #BCD955 !important;   
}

.top-bar-section ul li.active > a {
    background: #FF859C !important;   
}
```

But it's not working? That's the only editing I really did to it, but for the life of me I can't make it work for that one rectangle.

Yay! I can post images!

![enter image description here][1]

Well. Whilst finding the code bits to show y'all, I fixed it myself. So, thank you for making me walk through it more in depth!!

Instead of copying the code from Foundation's site, I found it in my base Foundation css file.

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .top-bar {
    background: #016B98;
    overflow: visible; }
    .top-bar:before, .top-bar:after {
      content: " ";
      display: table; }
    .top-bar:after {
      clear: both; }
    .top-bar .toggle-topbar {
      display: none; }
    .top-bar .title-area {
      float: left; }
    .top-bar .name h1 a {
      width: auto; }
    .top-bar input,
    .top-bar .button,
    .top-bar button {
      font-size: 0.875rem;
      position: relative;
      top: 7px; }
    .top-bar.expanded {
      background: #333333; }
```

Therefore, thank you for your help!

That first background bit is where I needed to be! For those that find this and are confused, this is what I was having trouble changing the color of (insert picture I still cannot post because you  need 10 for it!).

Anyway, thank you again. So very, very much!

Comment: you do have rep to post images now :)

Comment: Can we get a picture or some code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of the drop down arrow in Foundations menu, you just need to add this code to your app.css file.

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown>a:after {
border-top-color: #ff859C ;/*change to what ever color you would like*/
border-right-color: transparent;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

Note: If you are altering Foundations default styles in you normal css file, you will need to add the !important tag to the end of your style.

Comment: It's not the drop down that I need to change the color of. It's the space between all the buttons on my bar. It's all still default dark grey, and I need to change it to a blue color my client picked out.

Comment: I actually got it dealt with (finally). I'll mark this question answered =)